# Regular expression to include numbers but not others

Tags: python, regex

**Answered by npinti below. The C# answers were not helpful at all in the 'similar question'.**

So I have the following regex. I also tried different variations of this, but it will not work unfortunately.

So if I have the below string and would like to extract `23, 22 and 38`.
But I don't want it to extract the the numbers that are separated with a hyphen and also no negative numbers: `-`.

```
string = 'Have to find 23, but not 44-58 and definitely not 88-99 but do find 22 & 38' 

my_regex = re.compile(r'(\d+)|^((?![0-9]+[^-]^[0-9]+).)*$', flags=re.I)
print(my_regex.findall(string))
```

This basically returns nothing useful.

Comment: is it exactly 23, 22 & 38 you want to find? if not, can you be more specific?

Comment: What output does your regex show?

Comment: What about negative numbers (i.e. `this number -25 is negative`)?

Comment: Yes I would like to find exactly 23,22 and 38 as they are standalone numbers and no negative numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like so: `\b(?<!-)\d+(?!-)\b`. This will basically look for numbers which aren't preceded by a `-` and not followed by a `-` by using a negative look behind and negative look ahead.

Example [here](https://regex101.com/r/FSgmn4/1).

Note: The `\b` is there to ensure that given 12-34, the expression does not match `1` (since it is not followed by a `-`) and `4` (since it is not preceded by a `-`).

Comment: Works perfectly thank you! And for those looking at the C# question, the answers there did not work for me so this is not a duplicate. This answer actually works!

Comment: @N90J The solution there is working, you just need to replace `.` with `-`: https://ideone.com/sMz6Yo